# Why annotation default String is not identical although they must be constants

Tags: java, string, annotations, identity, java-annotations

I have a rough idea, but still would like to ask if anyone knows why `String` constants provided as annotation defaults change identity even though they reference static constants.

To illustrate, why does this code prints `true, true, false, false`.

```
@TestAnn
public class TestClass {

    public static final String STRING_CONSTANT = "SHOULD_BE_CONSTANT";

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface TestAnn {
        String value() default TestClass.STRING_CONSTANT;
    }
    public class OtherTestClass {
        String NOT_EVEN_STATIC = TestClass.STRING_CONSTANT;
    }
    private void run() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(STRING_CONSTANT == constantValue());

        System.out.println(STRING_CONSTANT == new OtherTestClass().NOT_EVEN_STATIC);

        String str1 = getClass().getAnnotation(TestAnn.class).value();
        System.out.println(STRING_CONSTANT == str1);

        String str2 = (String) TestAnn.class.getMethod("value").getDefaultValue();
        System.out.println(STRING_CONSTANT == str2);
    }
    private String constantValue() {
        return TestClass.STRING_CONSTANT;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestClass().run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky things is that when using `value()` or `getDefaultValue()` the real value is retrieved using reflection based on its runtime class, basically a new object String object (Type Object) is created and filled with the string value,

So when you trying to use == operator which compare Objects it will return false, but equal will return true because it compare the content,

the first two examples return true because you reference the same object, `constantValue()` return the same and `NOT_EVEN_STATIC` store same reference

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) to know why always String with constant values are always equal using ==  , for NOT_EVEN_STATIC example

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because the `String` value in really not the intern `String`, Let's find where the `String` in annotation from.

First we check code in `Class`, how it create annotation data.

```
private AnnotationData createAnnotationData(int classRedefinedCount) {
    Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation> declaredAnnotations =
        AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(getRawAnnotations(), getConstantPool(), this);
...
}
```

Then, go to the `AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations`, we find this:

```
private static Object parseConst(int tag, ByteBuffer buf, ConstantPool constPool) {
  ...
  case 's': return constPool.getUTF8At(constIndex);
  ...
}
```

So the `AnnotationParser` get the `String` value from `ConstantPool`. Let's get the value by ourselves:

```
Method m = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getConstantPool");
m.setAccessible(true);
ConstantPool pool = (ConstantPool) m.invoke(getClass());
```

Then get the `String` and its intern value, and compare them:

```
String str = pool.getUTF8At(9); // I find the index by traverse the pool, may different in your code
String intern = str.intern();
System.out.println(str == intern); // false
System.out.println(str == STRING_CONSTANT); // false
System.out.println(intern == STRING_CONSTANT); // true
```

So the `String` from `ConstantPool` is not the intern value. And I checked their id in eclipse

> str(id=371), intern(id=372)

So the truth is the `ConstantPool` do the `intern` on the constant String, but it returns the origin value it holds which is not intern.